# TextView как сделать перенос как есть

Tags: android

Можно ли как то включить на TextView перенос как есть, не реагируя на спец символы и тд. Тоесть все что поместилось то на первой строке, а то что не поместилось на следующую
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример, тут текст можно уместить на пару строк.

Answer (score 1):

Вся магия в атрибуте `android:hyphenationFrequency`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World! Then goes very looooooooooooooooong text and so on"
    android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
 />
```

Comment: к сожалению не работает,  причем,если убрать вопросительный знак из строки, то все работает как надо c этим параметром. Но к сожалению он там есть и убрать его нельзя так как это формат

Comment: В атрибуте `hyphenationFrequency` есть несколько параметров, попробуйте их

Comment: да, я все перебрал

Comment: Попробуйте еще поиграться с атрибутом `android:breakStrategy="simple/high_quality"`

Comment: Да, этот параметр я тоже сразу перебрал :( все равно бьет строку по вопросительному знаку